# How to use Spark Streaming to insert JSON data from Kafka into MySQL?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am learning to use Spark Steaming. Now I need to save the JSON format data in Kafka to the MySQL database through Spark Streaming. Now I can finish the data from Kafka, but I don't know how to further process it.

Comment: Instead spark streaming, you should use kafka connect

Comment: Agree with above, but what difficulties are you having using Spark JDBC writer?